# What causes "ETC1 cannot be resolved" errors when building AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

I just got the latest AndEngine code from Mercurial, added Android 1.6 to my Order/Export tab, and cleaned everything (including a "Fix" command as instructed by the console). Regardless of which version of Android I specify in my project settings (1.5, 1.6, 2.2, 3.2), I get around 523 compilation errors.

The most unique I can see is `ETC1 cannot be resolved`, accounting for 5 out of 105 errors I can see.

The other 100 are all some variation of `The method [...] must override a superclass method`.

What am I missing? I installed the JDK, Eclipse classic, SDK manager, and everything in the SDK.

Comment: tried the forums? http://www.andengine.org/forums/

Comment: Yeah, cross-posted to Gaming.SE and the forums.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the Compiler Compliance to 1.6, otherwise it will complain about almost every occurrence of an @Override annotation.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.andengine.org/forums/post21672.html this thread on the andengine forums, the reason is:

> Hey dude! That's because you're not using Android 2.2 in your project

Comment: I presume this means selecting "Android 2.2" in "Project Build Target." I tried this already, as I mentioned in my question, with various versions.